# AVL tree in C language

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

i am currently doing a project that requires the use of AVL trees ,
the insert function i wrote for the avl does not seem to be working , it works for 3 or 4 nodes at maximum ;

i would really appreciate your help
The attempt is below

```
Tree insert(Tree t,char name[80],int num)
{
  if(t==NULL)
  {
    t = (Tree)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(t! = NULL)
    {
      strcpy(t->name,name);
      t->num = num;
      t->left = NULL;
      t->right = NULL;
      t->height = 0;
    }
  }
  else if(strcmp(name,t->name)<0)
  {
    t->left = insert(t->left,name,num);

    if((height(t->left)-height(t->right))==2)
      if(strcmp(name,t->left->name)<0)
        t = s_rotate_left(t);
      else
        t = d_rotate_left(t);
  }
  else if(strcmp(name,t->name)>0)
  {
    t->right = insert(t->right,name,num);

    if((height(t->right)-height(t->left))==2)
      if(strcmp(name,t->right->name)>0)
        t = s_rotate_right(t);
      else
        t = d_rotate_right(t);
  }

  t->height = max(height(t->left),height(t->right))+1;

  return t;
}
```

Comment: @I_S_W, a couple of us went to the trouble of cleaning up your messy formatting, and then you completely screwed it up again. Please take the time to indent your code correctly, so that others don't have to spend more effort than necessary trying to help you. Also, don't use <code> and <pre>; just indent your code with four spaces.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos , Sorry dude didn't see that some1 edited the post, i did indent the code , but since i am using another computer i copied it from notepad therefore not indented
Thanks dude

Comment: That's ok, but it's still a mess. Do you plan to clean it up?

Comment: No, it's still a mess. The first line isn't even in the code block, there's a dozen empty lines, indentation almost random - practically unreadable.

Comment: Problem solved , the problem was in the rotation routines , Thanks for the indentation lesson:)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what sort of error you're getting, but there are a couple of things that need to be fixed.

You need to deside what you're going to do when the `malloc` fails. Right now you are setting `height` on a null pointer in that case.

If `height(NULL)` returns 0, then you are setting the height on a new node to 0 and then to 1. If it returns -1, then one of those assignments is redundant.

And you're calling `strcmp` twice for no good reason.

I suspect the real problem is buried in `s_rotate_left`, `d_rotate_left`, `s_rotate_right`, or `d_rotate_right`.