# avl tree help dictionary implementation

Tags: c, tree, avl-tree

i am currently learning c and algorithms.
I have implemented a mock up dictionary as a tree and would like to take my course work a bit further and use an avl tree.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define __USE_BSD
#include <string.h>

#include "speller.h"
#include "dict.h"

typedef struct node * tree_ptr;
struct node {
  Key_Type element; // only data is the key itself
  tree_ptr left, right;
  // add anything else that you need
};

struct table {
  tree_ptr head; // points to the head of the tree
  // add anything else that you need
}dictable;

Table initialize_table(/*ignore parameter*/) {
Table pointtable = malloc(sizeof(struct table));
return pointtable;
}
////


void insertnew(tree_ptr node, Key_Type element)
{
    Key_Type current = node->element;
    if(strcmp(element,current) < 0)//left
    {
      if(node -> left == NULL)
      {
        typedef struct node *pointsobject;
        //new sobject 
    pointsobject structsobject;
    // memory alocated
    structsobject = malloc(sizeof(*structsobject));
    structsobject-> element = element;
    structsobject-> left = NULL;
    structsobject-> right = NULL;
    node->left = structsobject;
      }
      else
        insertnew(node->left , element);
      }
      else if(strcmp(element,current) > 0)//right
      {
      if(node -> right == NULL)
      {
        typedef struct node *pointsobject;
        //new sobject 
    pointsobject structsobject;
    // memory alocated
    structsobject = malloc(sizeof(*structsobject));
    structsobject-> element = element;
    structsobject-> left = NULL;
    structsobject-> right = NULL;
    node->right = structsobject;
      }
      else
        insertnew(node->right, element);
      }

}



Table insert(Key_Type element,Table dictable) {
  if (dictable -> head == NULL)
  { 
   typedef struct node *pointsobject;
   //new sobject 
   pointsobject structsobject;
   // memory alocated
   structsobject = malloc(sizeof(*structsobject));
   structsobject-> element = element;
   structsobject-> left = NULL;
   structsobject-> right = NULL;
   dictable->head = structsobject;
  } 
  else
  {
    insertnew(dictable->head,element);
  }
  return dictable;
}

Boolean find(Key_Type element, Table dictable)  {
return FALSE;;
}


void printtab(tree_ptr node)
{
  if (node->left != NULL)
    printtab(node->left);
  if (node->right != NULL)
    printtab(node->right);
  printf("%s",node->element);
}

void print_table(Table dictable) {
printtab(dictable->head);
}


void print_stats (Table dictable) {
}
```

i have tried to look for an implementation online and find the explanations fairly confusing.
could someone point me in the right direction on how to change this tree structure into an avl tree structure.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by grabbing some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607456/avl-tree-in-c-language)

and I think [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) explains clearly enough about avl tree